# Как передать название товара в Форму оформления заказа,а также передать название товара в письме для покупателя и в письме продавцу о заказе

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Я создал сайт "Пряники от енота" на Wordpress.

Там есть страница заказов для каждого товара *http://pryaniki-ot-enota.kiev.ua/sdelat-zakaz*.

При нажатии на кнопку "Заказать товар" запускается "Форма оформления заказа" с последующей отсылкой подтверждения покупателю, а также проводится отсылка заявки продавцу о заказе товара.

Саму "Форму обратной связи для сайта с отправкой на почту" я взял с *https://itchief.ru/lessons/php/feedback-form-for-website*, разработанную Александром Мальцевым.

Вывод названия товара я сделал в цикле в виде записей Wordpress, а в середине цикла я вывел кнопку "Заказать товар":

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
?>
<form>
<a href='http://pryaniki-ot-enota.kiev.ua/wp-content/themes/bakes-and-cakes-enot/feedback/index.html' target="_blank"><img src="http://pryaniki-ot-enota.kiev.ua/wp-content/themes/bakes-and-cakes-enot/button_zakazat-tovar.png">
</form> 
<?php
the_post_navigation();
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
comments_template();
endif;

endwhile; 
?>
</main>
</div>
```

Форма обратной связи в целом работает, но покупателю приходится ручками вводить название заказанного товара.

Подскажите как сделать следующее:

1. Как передать название товара в вывод "Формы оформления заказа";
2. Как передать название товара в письме для подтверждения покупателю, а также в письме-заявке продавцу о заказе товара.

WooCommerce я не использовал в разработке этого сайта.

Сам автор этой "Формы обратной связи для сайта с отправкой на почту" в комментариях оставил мой вопрос без ответа.

Здесь ссылка на файлы (Github) с кодом Формы обратной связи для сайта с отправкой на почту.  [Форма обратной связи с отправкой на почту](https://github.com/itchief/feedback-form/tree/master/feedback)

Answer (score 0):

1. Сделать всплывающую форму и передавать название товара и его id посредством js.
2. Формировать нормальную корзину, например, что делать, если я хочу заказать несколько товаров сразу, поменять кол-во каждой позиции?

Comment: Приветствую, @DaemonHK!    Всплывающая форма работает нормально. Вся проблема в том, что как из нижеприведенного цикла Wordpress:

    '<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    ?>'

передать название записи (название товара) в вывод "Формы оформления заказа".  
А также передать название записи (название товара) в письме для подтверждения 
покупателю, а также в письме-заявке продавцу о заказе товара.

Comment: @SerhejSkvortsov что мешает не использовать the_post(), а выводить записи самостоятельно, передавая нужные данные через data-параметры и отлавливать их посредством js?

Comment: Приветствую, @DaemonHK!  У Вас интересная идея, но как это выразить в коде РНР и JS?